# jQuery Bootstrap Tooltip setting margin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, margin

I show tooltips on mouseover divs - see Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0egk47n9/34/

But I can't set margins for the tooltips. None of the following seems to have any effect on the tooltip position:

```
.pin .tooltip.left {
    margin-left: -50px !important;
    left: -50px !important;
}
.pin .tooltip.right {
    margin-right: 50px !important;
    right: 50px !important;
}
```

[SOLVED]

The following works:

```
.pic .tooltip.right {
  margin-left: 20px !important;
}
.pic .tooltip.left {
  margin-left: -20px !important;
}
```

Note! Both tooltip margins are shifted from the left!
See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0egk47n9/70/

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can solve your problem

```js
$('.pic').on('mouseover', '.pin', function(e) {
  $(this).attr('title', 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz');
  $(this).tooltip({
    placement: function(context, source) {
      var position = $(source).position();

      if (position.left > 220) {
        return "left";
      }

      if (position.left < 220) {
        return "right";
      }
    }
  });
  $(this).tooltip('show');
});
```

```css
.pic {
  width: 70%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.pin {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

//For Bootstrap 3.3.7
.tooltip {
  display: block;
}

.fade.right.in,
.fade.left.in {
  top: 50px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="pic">
  <div class="pin left" data-toggle="tooltip">
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  </div>
  <div class="pin right in" data-toggle="tooltip">
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .pin .tooltip.fade.right.in,
.pin .tooltip.fade.left.in {
  left: 50px !important;
}  - does't work

Comment: Yes I know. I am trying to find solution.

Comment: just FYI - I need to tie my tooltips only to my block, so that the rest of the site tooltip behavior is not affected

Comment: I got it! (see above)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing "+" in your css selector, because the tooltip's html was appended after(below) the main div (the one that has class "pin"), not appended inside the main div

So your css should be:

```
.pin + .tooltip.left {
    margin-left: -50px !important;
    left: -50px !important;
}
.pin + .tooltip.right {
    margin-right: 50px !important;
    right: 50px !important;
}
```